# How to iterate over this object and display them in a comma separated way?

Tags: javascript

I have a small array.

```
var a = [{"id":"firstName","value":["Sam3","Sam5"]},{"id":"lastName","value":["Jones4","Jones5"]}]
```

How to display the values likes this

```html
<div>
<span>key1val: key2val0,key2val1 </span> // firstName: Sam3, Sam5 (for object 1)
<span>key1val: key2val0,key2val1 </span> .... so on  lastName: Jones4, Jones5 (for object 1)
</div>
```

I am able to do this without loop since I am a small object at this moment. But I want to do this via loop to accommodate big objects. I am using this for React. This is Demo Fiddle - [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wowxz9jmv8)

Comment: Please show example of your working code right now.

Comment: @joelgullander Here is my silly way. first_names_label = "First Name:";
      first_names = this.state.filtered[0].value.map(name => <p>{name}</p>);
      last_names_label = "Last Name:";
      last_names = this.state.filtered[1].value.map(name => <p>{name}</p>);

Comment: Please update first post with the example together with proper formatting please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using react you can do it like

```
a.map((obj,key) =>(
     <span key={key}>
         {obj.id}:  {obj.value.join(',')}
     </span>
))
```

or

```
a.map((obj,key) =>(
     <span key={key}>
         {obj.id}:
         {
             obj.value.map((name, key) => (
                 <span key={key}>{name}</span>
             ))
          }
     </span>
))
```

Comment: Can you kindly fork and show me the usage here in this fiddle - https://codesandbox.io/s/wowxz9jmv8

Comment: Can you kindly fork and show me the usage here in this fiddle (kindly use the first method)?

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is to create a html table so you don't have to iterate two times by first getting firstnames and then lastnames.

Then you could do something like:

```
return (
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
        </tr>
        {a.map(item => (
            <tr>
                <td>{item.firstName}</td>
                <td>{item.lastName</td>
            </tr>
        )}
    </table>
)
```

Comment: Can you kindly fork and show me the usage here in this fiddle - https://codesandbox.io/s/wowxz9jmv8

Comment: I am not going to use any table related elements for this

Comment: Well unfortunately your question is not expressed well so I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.. :) good luck!